# Sine Over Cosine Limit Doubt

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Intuitively, I suppose that:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{x + 5 \sin x}{x-\cos x} = 1$

Analytically, though, I get stuck at $\cos / \sin$ limits...

Thanks.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x) \ge \frac {x-5}{x+1}$$
$$f(x) \le \frac {x+5}{x-1}$$

The limit of each as $x \to \infty$ is  equal to $1$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x + 5\sin(x)}{x-\cos(x)} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1+5\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1-\frac{\cos x}{x}}=1$$